# What jQuery selector combination can I use to hide TD parents that don't contain search?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table that displays all classes available.  The TR ID for each class is the class provider+grade level  (Example:  8th grade Virtual class would be "Virtual8").  I then have a 'Provider' combo box, 'Grade' combo box, and 'Class Title' text box.  When you click 'Display' it should hide all TRs, show TRs that display the correct 'Provider'+'Grade' ID, and then hide any TD's parent(tr) that does not contain the class search.

Currently the class title search does nothing at all it appears.

I know this is very confusing, and there is probably an easier way to do it.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  If I leave the 'Class Title' box blank and search just for provider and grade level, the form works fine; however, adding a class title in the search does nothing.

The Code:

```
<script src="jquery.missing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#display").click(function() { 

        $('tr[id^="Independent"]').hide();
        $('tr[id^="Virtual"]').hide();
        $('tr[id^="Innovative"]').hide();
        $('tr[id^="Lincoln"]').hide();
        $('tr[id^="Missouri"]').hide();
        $('tr[id^="Calvert"]').hide();

        var result = $('#theprovider').val() + $('#thegrade').val();
        $('tr[id*="' + result + '"]').show();

        var search = $('#searchclass').val();
        $('td:missing("' + search + '")').closest('tr').hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

Missing.js Code (provided by Darcy Clarke):

```
$.expr[':'].missing = function(elem, index, match) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || Sizzle.getText([elem]) || "").indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
}
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this, ignore the `\"`, that is more than likely from the server-code. Can be read as `"`

Comment: Yes, my fault.  The code is in PHP inside of a string - will update post.

Comment: Where is the search taking place? In PHP? Then why render the rows and force JS to hide them? If the search is taking place in JS, then why is all this getting rendered in a PHP string? My suggestion would be to simplify the problem by rendering all this in one language or the other. If it doesn't evaporate magically, then you can repost a more concise question.

Comment: Additionally, there is no example here of what you're actually trying to do and the explanation is vague. Could you show an example of the HTML getting utilized? The table and the button? Maybe a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape doubt quotes only if they are used inside enclosing double quotes, same applies to single quotes too.

Instead of `missing` you can try using combination of `not` and `contains` like this.

```
$('tr:gt(0)').not(":contains('" + search + "')").hide();
```

Comment: I have tried that exact code.  When I run that, all classes hide - nothing stays shown.  Without that line, the tr's with the correct ID show up fine.

Comment: @Fleppar - Try my edited answer, I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This worked fine, I apologize for the vague description - I'm unaware how else to explain it without rambling.  

I don't quite understand why you would search the TR and not the TD?  Thank you very much for the help though!

Comment: The only problem I see with that line is that the table headers are also being hidden when that search is executed.

Comment: @Fleppar - You can use `tr:gt(0)` if first row is the header row.

Comment: Still no luck, even with the gt(0).  The table headers are on the first TR of the table, so that should work.